# Core Data, iCloud, and stock objects

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, icloud, merging-data

I'm updating a local Core Data-driven app to support iCloud.  One challenge I anticipate is around what I'm calling "stock objects" -- seed data the app provides at first launch that 99% of users will customize.

**Stock Objects**

```
Item A
Item B
```

**Customized Objects**

```
Tomatoes
Potatoes
```

If the user then launches the app for the first time on a new device, I think the default behavior would be for the re-creation of the stock objects which would get merged with the customized objects from the iCloud persistent store (Item A, Item B, Tomatoes, Potatoes), resulting in a messy user experience.

One approach might be to check for iCloud data synchronously at first launch, and if it exists, not create the stock objects.  But still, the user could be offline on first launch, and then on second launch, the same undesirable merge of local stock objects with iCloud custom objects would happen.

Are there ways to add logic to iCloud merges, so that the arrival of customized objects from the cloud (Tomatoes and Potatoes) can signal me to delete local stock objects (Item A and Item B) before they get beamed up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but this is what I'm doing:

1. When the user elects to enable iCloud, I check if their iCloud directory is empty.
2. If so, no problem; I migrate the database to a new local store that has iCloud options enabled so that all existing data moves to the cloud.
3. If not, I check if the local database is empty.  If it is, I wipe out all the stock objects and take everything from the cloud.  If it isn't, I tell the user currently the app can't merge a local database with an iCloud database, and ask them to delete their data (or reinstall), thus sidestepping this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just avoid this by not providing seed objects? Simply prompt the user through the UI to enter his own objects on first launch. Ask, if she has used the app before and explain that it might pay to wait to sync from iCloud before recreating the objects.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I want to trouble the user with that upfront.  The other issue is that there are entire Entities full of stock objects that I need to deal with in a special way.  Imagine stock FoodType objects ("Meat," "Vegetable," "Dessert," etc.), in a relationship with the Foods entities.  Even if all their properties match, if they were created at different times on different devices, Core Data seems to see them as distinct.  So when the merge happens, suddenly I have two "Meat" FoodTypes, with some foods linked to one object and some linked to the other.

Comment: I had a similar case. I provided seed objects that were useful - most of them never got changed. One simple idea is to add a boolean attribute `validated` and take the logic from there. You could then check for equivalence and "merge" in the background without the user noticing.